# ExtJs 4 Grid - Column selection list as separate menu button

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I want to display de grid column selector (https://i.stack.imgur.com/4YGOs.jpg) as a separate Menu Button in the grid toolbar... i'm pretty lost as to how to achieve this.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use `gridRef.headerCt.getMenu()`

sample fiddle: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/4pq

Comment: diggin up a little more i found that grid.headerCt.getColumnMenu(grid.headerCt) and adding that array of items to the new button menu was exactly what i needed, without needing to clone the component or anything like it